# Data Sync between server and multiple clients

Tags: android, ios, mobile, webservice-client, data-synchronization

I developed an application which requires constant updates from server whenever data changes with respect to a specific user. e.g A user will be notified of all the changes or on goings if he/she is either a service provider, customer or a business owner. So currently whenever a change is occurred I send out a notification and on client end I update the UI based upon the notification details.

My question is: Is there any other way where I could minimize the notifications ?

Can I wire my mobile(Android/iOS) app with a session based service ? If yes then how ? And will the session maintainance be costly interms of resources ?

Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would test if polling the server for update information is more efficient, because in many cases the client just doesn't need the updates for whatever reason (the app is in background, for example).

Comment: You can reduce the notifications by checking if the app is active or not. For that what you can do is whenever the app becomes active/inactive, notify the server about the status of the app. This way you can avoid sending notification when the app is inactive.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Please do, but polling the server after a specific time is not a good choice

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the notifications by checking if the app is active or not. For that what you can do is whenever the app becomes active/inactive, notify the server about the status of the app. This way you can avoid sending notification when the app is inactive.

Comment: Well did that already. Still need to analyze any other possible solution. i.e for updating UI creating a sync service would be good choice or not as that way I have to maintain sessions and that will be costly.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Can you explain what you desire to acheive and what's the bottle necks in your current implementation?